# Apache http server rewrite url failed

Tags: java, apache, web, httpserver

I want to redirect the `http://www.example.com/index.htm` to
local file: /home/admin/mf/htdocs/default.htm
config the apache server in httpd.conf as below, but it does't work, any problem 
with my configuration?

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/admin/mf/htdocs
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/index.htm /default.htm
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your rule works just fine for me. See @nfechner's answer below for your possible missing configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing a `<Directory>` directive for the document root `/home/admin/mf/htdocs`:

```
<Directory /home/admin/mf/htdocs>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
<Directory>
```

For more information see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory).

Comment: and I try to redriect the request to local file using the absolute path does't work either:                                            RewriteRule ^/index.htm /home/admin/test/default.htm